# Minimalist way of sending plain text to another computer

Tags: command-line, terminal, powershell

I'm new to powershell and windows, I want to know a simple and elegant way of sending small size plain text to another computer.
I know you could do this very easily in Linux/OSX shell using:

```
ls | mail <my@email>
```

Both powershell equivalent or other approaches are appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking how to email from command line or some other message system (like alerts or something)?

Comment: not necessarily using email, just looking for a very simple way to send text to another device

Comment: On the other side of the world or on the same network?

Comment: Bluetooth, perhaps?

Comment: have you taken a look at this Question & its Answers yet? [*grin*]

Comment: you need to explain a little more what "sending to another computer" is. do you want to show the text to the currently logged in user on the remote comp.? do you want to store the text on the remote computers filesystem? do you want to send it by mail? that's not clear at the moment

Comment: @KeithMiller on a different network

Answer (score 1):

This is not a PowerShell-specific thing. It's been doable well before PowerShell ever existed. You've been able to do this in Windows for decades via a built-in Windows executable.

```
Syntax
      MSG username [options] [message]
      MSG sessionname [options] [message]
      MSG sessionid   [options] [message]
      MSG  @filename [options] [message]
      MSG * [options] [message]

Options
   username            The user to send to, * will send to all sessions on the machine.
   /SERVER:servername  The server to contact (default is current).
   /TIME:seconds       Time delay to wait for receiver to acknowledge msg.
   /V                  Verbose, display extra information.
   /W                  Wait for response from user, useful with /V.
   message             The message text to send, some special characters may
                       have to be escaped.


# Examples
msg User1 "Let's meet at 1PM today"

# Example - additional data to see what the user did with the message
msg $env:USERNAME /w /v "Let's meet at 1PM today"

# Results of the user reposne
<#
Sending message to session Console, display time 60
Message to session Console responded to by user
#>
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg

The full PowerShell way of doing the same is just calling the same executable.

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "msg * 'help me'" -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Yet, sometimes, old school is best.

Just know the moment you go to Powershell v7, WMI cmdlets, and the like are not in there. Specifically, because PSv7 is cross-platform, and there is no WMI stack on them.

***Point of note:***

Msg.exe does not exist on all Windows OS versions, for example, Windows Home editions.

***The users must be on your network!!!***

If they are not, then you have a whole different issue, which would require other configs and or tools/approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to copy data in a file from one computer to another is Copy-Item.
This presumes the two computers are on the same network, in some sense.

You can read the help file for Copy-Item [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1).

If you really have to use email to convey the data, you can use the Send-MailMessage cmdlet.  You can read the help file for Send-MailMessage [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.1)